Scansion of a line in Yeats' "An Irish Airman Foresees His Death"?
"An Irish Airman Foresees His Death" holds a firm iambic tetrametric rhythm throughout, except for line 8, which includes 9 syllables:

Or leave them happier than before;

How would you scan this line? Would "-pier than" count as an anapaest?

The line can easily be read as eight syllables (Ha-pyer).

It’s a convention in English verse that an occasional iambic foot can contain two unstressed syllables instead of one, if the two unstressed syllables can, in theory or practice, be “elided” (that is, merged or blended together). John Crowe Ransom presented this as the first of a list of four customary exceptions in his discussion of iambic pentameter:

Strictly speaking, each of the five feet should be iambic. But that proved hard to manage in any spirited and spontaneous kind of language. Custom quickly came to license the following exceptions, and if we must date the event it was during that period when modern English was finding its poetic language, a period concluded triumphantly in the verse of Sidney and Spenser.

Two unstressed syllables could replace the one which iambic permits, if “elision” was possible whether actually in speech, or only theoretically.

John Crowe Ransom (1956). ‘The Strange Music of English Verse’. The Kenyon Review 18:3, p. 471.

We can put examples of this phenomenon into a rough order according to how hard it would be to elide the two unstressed syllables if reading the poem out loud.
At the easy end are are lines like these, where the elisions would work even in ordinary speech. (Bold text in these examples indicates multiple unstressed syllables where just one would be expected if the line were perfectly iambic.)

Lo in the orient when the gracious light [Shakespeare, Sonnet 7]
Of man’s first disobedience, and the fruit [Milton, Paradise Lost 1.1]
The world, as usual, wickedly inclined [Byron, Don Juan 1.149]
And I who have written much in prose and verse [Browning, Aurora Leigh 1.2]

Further along, we find cases which would not normally be elided in speech, but which we could plausibly elide if we were reading the poem out loud, without sounding forced or unnatural:

I sigh the lack of many a thing I sought [Shakespeare, Sonnet 30]
Neither a borrower nor a lender be [Shakespeare, Hamlet I.3]
For those rebellious; here their prison ordained [Milton, Paradise Lost 1.71]
Abominable, inutterable, and worse [Milton, Paradise Lost 2.626]
Still drop by drop adown the finger of God [Browning, Aurora Leigh 5.5]

At the difficult end of the scale we find cases that can't be elided without sounding forced or unnatural, and we do better to read them as anapests:

Than carry it but by the suit of the gentry to him [Shakespeare, Coriolanus II.1]
Two onely, who yet by sov’ran gift possess [Milton, Paradise Lost 5.366]
Bring round the heart an undescribable feud [Keats, ‘On Seeing the Elgin Marbles’]
Tickling men’s ears—the sect for a quarter of an hour [Browning, The Ring and the Book 1.305]

The line from Yeats in the question is towards the easy end of this scale.
Notes for prosodists

Some writers make a fine distinction between “elision” proper, where two vowels merge, as in “orient” or “disobedience”, and “contraction”, where one vowel disappears, as in “pris’n ordained” or “fing’r of God”. I find it simpler to lump the two phenomena into one category, but if the distinction makes sense to you there’s nothing wrong with it.

Paradise Lost 2.626 has caused a surprising amount of trouble over the years. I scan it regularly as “Abom’nable, inutt’rable, and worse” which trips nicely off the tongue, but Brydges gives this scansion:

Abō|mĭnā|blĕ, ĭnūt|tĕrā|blĕ ānd | wōrse
Egerton Brydges, editor (1835). The Poetical Works of John Milton, volume 5, page 5. London: John Macrone.

It is hardly credible that Milton intended the line to be read like this, with the final stress on its own in a sixth “demi-foot”. That Brydges should consider this plausible is so odd that it makes me wonder if the pronunciation of the words has changed. Was it really “abominable” in the 19th century?



IIt's not hard to pronounce the heroic turnpike road in an iambic line. Drop the /h/ in heroic, and blur the 'e'of the and the 'e' of heroic together. Alexander Pope probably did something like this in the line: "Who give th' hysteric, or poetic fit." When I recite it this way, it's not perfectly iambic, but it's at the "easy end" of the spectrum.

I personally don't find anything unnatural about dropping an 'h' in an unaccented first syllable (see all the discussions about an historic on English.SE). And you shouldn't insist that your own accent is the only way to scan all poetry—this is undoubtedly where Bridges went wrong in his scansion of Abominable, unutterable, and worse.

There are two ways to scan the line: either -pier /piər/ is two syllables and -pier than counts as an anapest, or, as @Kate Bunting remarks in a comment, pier /pjər/ is one syllable (that starts with the consonant cluster "py") and -pier than counts as an iamb.
I can't think of any reason to prefer one over the other.

For the anapest, it's two short, one long. I don't see how happier can be that. Hap-pi-er is one long, two short. Or three syllables equally stressed. Hap-pi-er.

@Lambie: No, the scansion would be | Or léave | them háp-| pier thán | befóre |, with the whole line being two iambs, an anapest, and a final iamb. In English poetry, feet do not have to respect word boundaries. (And English almost never stresses three-syllable words with equal stresses.)

I get what you mean now. But I still don't get your feet. |Or leave them|hap-pi-er|than|before. makes it 9 for me, like the OP. Yes, one can do: ha-pyer for 8. When you read "leave them", it's not natural for me to stress leave and put them in the next foot.

@Lambie: there are conventions for scanning English poetry that your suggested scansion does not conform with.

Scansion is not a one-stop shop (only one way to scan a poem), as you yourself have pointed out: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571537/iambic-pentameter-stress-and-monosyllables Kate says it can be ha-pyer for 8, but that is not the only reading. I hope I don't get another mod. letter saying I am arguing. My opinion is in good faith.

Metrical English poetry especially in Yeats' time is/was done by counting stressed and unstressed syllables; viewing it as based on feet of short and long syllables is something only a student of classical poetry would do.
